# Как объединить в SQL по параметру?

Tags: sql, база-данных, union

Что имеется ввиду?
Например, необходимо объединить первую таблицу (tab1) со второй таблицей (tab2) по столбцам NAME и AGE.

**tab1:**

```
NAME    AGE CITY  
------------------
jack    18  moscow  
bob     35  london  
oliver  22  madrid
```

**tab2:**

```
NAME    AGE CITY  
------------------  
jack    70  omsk  
bob     35  peterburg  
oliver  55  krasnodar
```

Должна получиться вот такая итоговая таблица:

```
NAME    AGE CITY  
------------------
jack    18  moscow  
bob     35  london  
oliver  22  madrid  
jack    70  omsk  
oliver  55  krasnodar
```

Comment: А почему из двух строк bob 35 был выбран london, а не peterburg?

Comment: И укажите какой именно диалект sql (какой sql-сервер) вас интересует

Comment: В общем случае это имеется в виду `ON table1.name=table2.name AND table1.age=table2.age`.

Comment: все, понял, что данный запрос не имеет смысла

Answer (score 0):

Работает в Sql Server:

```
select
    isnull(tab1.[NAME], tab2.[NAME]),
    isnull(tab1.[AGE],  tab2.[AGE]),
    isnull(tab1.[CITY], tab2.[CITY])
from tab1
full join tab2
on tab1.[NAME] = tab2.[NAME] and tab1.[AGE] = tab2.[AGE]
```

Comment: Объединение через соединение. Извращение, конечно, но сработает.

Answer (score 0):

Судя по предоставленному примеру, речь идет не об объединении по столбцам, а о группировке результатов объединения.

```
SELECT
  name,
  age,
  min(city) as city
FROM (
  SELECT name, age, city FROM tab1
  UNION
  SELECT name, age, city FROM tab2
)
GROUP BY name, age
```

Comment: там не `min`, а строка из первого набора.

Comment: @teran, откуда вы знаете? Автор на прямой вопрос промолчал

Answer (score -1):

А не проще использовать оператор UNION

```
select * from tab1
union 
select * from tab2
```

Comment: Это не даст желаемый результат.